# WPF mediaElement source switching

Tags: c#, wpf, video, media

I am planning to play a certain video using `MediaElement`. If the user presses a button->that video is switched to a different one and plays. Thing is, whenever I change the `mediaElement.Source` to the second video(and then play it), there are a few seconds of a black screen indicating the process of switching the videos. How can I achieve the effect that the videos switch right away? instead of the delayed screen.. Perhaps using several `MediaElement`s? Thanks in advance for any light on that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest trying another `MediaElement` in which you hook the `MediaOpened` event and switch the element into view once it's fired.  Make sure that you call `Stop()` on the prior element to ensure that it stops playing and is cleaned up.

Comment: Can you further explain your suggestion? I haven't gotten the hang of it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  You would have two MediaElements, one of them hidden/collapsed and the other one displaying the current video.  When the user clicks the button you would swap the visibility of the two elements.  I'm not sure if this is possible since I don't know your application, but you may want to set the `LoadedBehavior` property of the background element to *Manual* and leave it paused, only playing it once the user clicks the button.  Of course, if the user is selecting a video from a list of options this may not be feasible.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that there are apparently several bugs/issues prior to .NET 4.0 with this elemenet, in case you're on an earlier framework.